# Why was there a kid running with a Uchiha crest on his jacket iafter the Uchiha ending?

Tags: naruto

Why was there a kid running with a Uchiha crest on his jacket in *Naruto Shippuden* after the uchiha ending?

Did another Uchiha survive that no know one knows about? Or did he find the missing jacket and is wearing it? Or did he survive then later dies?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot and episode number?